# Fetch() is not returning data from server in response

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, promise, fetch

I'm having an issue with my fetch returning any data from the server and I can't quite seem to understand why.

I thought maybe the promise was resolving before the server was sending back any JSON so I recently updated my model to utilize promises as well.  I'm new to promises and the fetch API so bear with me.

> I am willing to revert back too callbacks and put my `Player.find` and `Player.create` methods back in
>   the `Players.js` route and avoid promises on the server side altogether.

**Player Model (after adding promise)**

```
// require mongoose for data modeling
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Q from 'q';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// define player schema
const PLAYER_SCHEMA = new Schema({
  name: String,
  score: Number
});

PLAYER_SCHEMA.statics.createPlayer = (name, score) => {
  const deferred = Q.defer();

  Player.create({
    name,
    score,
  }, (error, player) => {
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject(new Error(error));
    }

    deferred.resolve(player);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}

PLAYER_SCHEMA.statics.getPlayers = () => {
  const deferred = Q.defer();

  Player.find({})
    .sort({
      score: 'desc'
    })
    .limit(5)
    .exec((error, players) => {
        if (error) {
          deferred.reject(new Error(error));
        }

        deferred.resolve(players);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}

let Player = mongoose.model('Player', PLAYER_SCHEMA);

// first param is the singular name for the collection,
// mongoose automatically looks for the plural version
// so our db will have a 'players' collection
export default Player;
```

**Route (after adding promise)**

```
// dependencies
import express from 'express';
import Player from '../models/player';

const ROUTER = express.Router();

ROUTER.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const score = req.body.score;
  const promise = Player.createPlayer(name, score);

  promise.then((response) => {
    res.status(201).json(response);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.send(err)
  });

});

ROUTER.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const promise = Player.getPlayers();

  promise.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    res.status(200).json(response);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.send(err)
  });
});

export default ROUTER;
```

Testing these endpoints works fine in Postman, so I assume the issue does not lie on the server.

This is where I suspect I have an issue.

**Client.js (where AJAX methods are stored)**

```
function createPlayer(playerData, onError, cb) {
  return fetch('/api/players', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(playerData),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  }).then(checkStatus)
    .then(cb)
    .catch(onError);
}

function getPlayers(success, onError) {
  return fetch('/api/players', {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  }).then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(success)
    .catch(onError);
}

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  } else {
    const error = new Error(`HTTP Error ${response.statusText}`);
    error.status = response.statusText;
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}

const Client = {
  createPlayer,
  getPlayers
};
export default Client;
```

**App.jsx (a lot of code omitted)**

// all other code omitted

```
  const playerData = {
    name,
    score: this.state.totalScore,
  };

  client.createPlayer(playerData,
    (err) => {
      // TODO: improve error message
      console.log(err);
    },
    client.getPlayers((data) => {
      // array of objects containing all but most recent entry
      console.log(data); 
      this.setState({
        inputScreen: false, // hide the input screen
        highScoreScreen: true, // show the high score screen
        yeti: yetiWin,
        highScores: [...this.state.highScores, ...data],
      });
    }, (err) => {
      // TODO: improve this error message
      console.log(err);
    })
  );
```

// all other code omitted

The data variable never contains the newly created player, but it does contain other players. So the create and read operations are working on the server-side. When I modify my `App.jsx` to something like below:

**App.jsx (trial)**

```
  const playerData = {
    name,
    score: this.state.totalScore,
  };

  client.createPlayer(playerData,
    (err) => {
      // TODO: improve error message
      console.log(err);
    },
    (res) => {
      // should contain something like:
      // {
      //     "__v": 0,
      //     "_id": "5881922f441fda40ccc52f83",
      //     "name": "player name",
      //     "score": "123"
      // }
      // right?
      console.log(res.json());
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.body);
    }
  );
```

When I log `res.json` `res` and `res.body` I get:

> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
>
> Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/players", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK"…}
>
> ReadableStream {}

When I test my POST endpoint (`http://localhost:3001/api/players`) in postman the server responds with a JSON object containing the data I want.  For whatever reason `client.createPlayer` doesn't return the data from the server.  Of course, that's only part of the problem.

In theory, once my `client.createPlayer` resolves and I invoke `client.getPlayers` as the callback to `client.createPlayer` that method should return the data I want including the newly created player, right?

However that doesn't seem to be the case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this `http://localhost:3001` looks suspicious ... I take it `http://localhost:3001` is also where the page that is making the request is loaded from, not from a different host like `http://localhost:80` or something - I can see your URL in the fetch is `'/api/players'` so, that's the ACTUAL code, you haven't removed anything just for the question, it's not a "cross origin" request, is it?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using create-react-app so the client server is running on localhost:3000 and the express server is running on localhost:3001. Client is setup to proxy requests to localhost:3001.

Comment: ok - just making sure it's not a CORS issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, by changing the code in my `App.jsx` to the following I was able to produce the results I'm after.  However, I'm not going to mark my answer as the correct solution as I do not fully understand why this change made it work.

If anyone would like to chime in and explain why this now works I would love to hear the reason why.

**App.jsx (fixed)**

```
// all other code omitted 

  client.createPlayer(playerData, (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }, (data) => {
    this.setState({
      highScores: [...this.state.highScores, ...data],
    });
  });      

  client.getPlayers((data) => {
    this.setState({
      inputScreen: false, // hide the input screen
      highScoreScreen: true, // show the high score screen
      yeti: yetiWin,
      highScores: [...this.state.highScores, ...data],
    });
  }, (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

// all other code omitted
```

You'll note that I am no longer invoking `client.getPlayers` as the success callback to `client.createPlayer`.  On top of that I'm using the returned data from `client.createPlayer` and adding it to the state as a fallback in the event the `client.createPlayer` method does not finish before the `client.getPlayers` method. This would ensure that the new player is displayed once `setState` issues a re-render.